# How do I count a specific character that is surrounded by random letters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to count punctuations that are: apostrophe (') and hyphen (-) using dictionaries. I want to see if I can pull this off using list/dictionary/for loops and boolean expressions. These punctuations MUST ONLY BE COUNTED if they are surrounded by any other letters! E.g. jack-in-a-box (that is 3 hyphens) and shouldn't (1 apostrophe). These letters can be anything from a to z. Also, since this is part of an assignment, no modules/libraries can be used. I'm out of ideas and don't know what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I tried: but I get an KeyError: 0

```
def countpunc2():
filename = input("Name of file? ")
text = open(filename, "r").read()
text = text.lower()  #make all the words lowercase (for our convenience)
for ch in '!"#$%&()*+./:<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
    text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
for ch in '--':
    text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
words = text.split('\n')       #splitting the text for words
wordlist = str(words)
count = {}                 #create dictionary; the keys/values are added on
punctuations = ",;'-"
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i, char in enumerate(wordlist):
    if i < 1:
        continue
    if i > len(wordlist) - 2:
        continue
    if char in punctuations:
        if char not in count:
            count[char] = 0
        if count[i-1] in letters and count[i+1] in letters:
            count[char] += 1
print(count)
```

UPDATE: 
I changed the code to:

```
def countpunc2():
filename = input("Name of file? ")
text = open(filename, "r").read()
text = text.lower()  #make all the words lowercase (for our convenience)
for ch in '!"#$%&()*+./:<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
    text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
for ch in '--':
    text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
words = text.split('\n')       #splitting the text for words
wordlist = str(words)
count = {}                 #create dictionary; the keys/values are added on
punctuations = ",;'-"
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for i, char in enumerate(wordlist):
    if i < 1:
        continue
    if i > len(wordlist) - 2:
        continue
    if char in punctuations:
        if char not in count:
            count[char] = 0
        if wordlist[i-1] in letters and wordlist[i+1] in letters:
            count[char] += 1
print(count)
```

While it is giving me an output it is not correct.
Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kqwvudflxnmldqr/sample1.txt?dl=0
The expected results must be: {',' : 27, '-' : 10, ';' : 5, "'" : 1}

Comment: post the sample file

Comment: Post a sample string as an input and excepted output

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new here I'll edit it.

Comment: When you edit a question that has been answered and fundamentally change the question, please append it as an update instead of deleting what the question originally asked.

Comment: I understand. Sorry about that. Like I said, I'm kind of new here (and clearly inexperienced in writing any normal question posts).

Comment: Can you tell us the value of `wordlist`?

Comment: wordlist is basically the entire document. As you can see, I open and read a file (may or may not be a .txt file but it can be read), I grab all the text and make it lowercase and remove all the useless characters like ?+# etc. which are only making my job harder for counting other important characters. The wordlist is me turning these into a string (although I was thinking if I should turn it into an actual list instead to enumerate).

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of it? Are you sure it isn't empty?

Comment: Found your issue, please check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the characters of your input string into 3 categories:  alphabetic(a), punctuation(p) and spaces(s). Then group them in triples (sequences of 3 characters). From those, isolate the a-p-a triples and count the number of distinct punctuation characters.

for example:

```
string="""jack-in-a-box (that is 3 hyphens) and shouldn't (1 apostrophe)."""

categ   = [ "pa"[c.isalpha()] if c != " " else "s" for c in string ]
triples = [ triple for triple   in zip(categ,categ[1:],categ[2:]) ]
pChars  = [ p      for p,triple in zip(s[1:],triples) if triple==("a","p","a") ]
result  = { p:pChars.count(p) for p in set(pChars) }

print(result) # {"'": 1, '-': 3}
```

If you're not allowed to use `isAlpha()` or `zip()`, you can code the equivalent using the `in` operator and `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does it in a very spelled out way:

```
end_cap_characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
special_characters = [";", ":", "'", "-", ","]

def count_special_characters(in_string):
    result = {}
    for i in range(1, len(in_string) - 1):
        if in_string[i - 1] in end_cap_characters:
            if in_string[i + 1] in end_cap_characters:
                if in_string[i] in special_characters:
                    if in_string[i] not in result:
                        result[in_string[i]] = 1
                    else:
                        result[in_string[i]] +=1
    return result

print(count_special_characters("jack-in-the-box"))
print(count_special_characters("shouldn't"))
print(count_special_characters("jack-in-the-box, shouldn't and a comma that works,is that one"))
```

Output:

```
{'-': 3}
{"'": 1}
{'-': 3, "'": 1, ',': 1}
```

Obviously this can be condensed, but I will leave that as an exercise for you ;).

**Update**

Based on your edited question and posted code, you need to update the line:

```
if count[i-1] in letters and count[i+1] in letters:
```

to:

```
if wordlist[i-1] in letters and wordlist[i+1] in letters:
```

Comment: I'm assuming I can condense it using enumerate?

Comment: Yes, `enumerate` will loop you through the string, just like what is being done above, but also gives you the index and the character as you loop, so you don't have to pull it as a step. I was also meaning something like consolidating all of the character checking `if` statements into a one liner or shortening variable names.

Comment: Hmmm, it's weird I tried that and now I am getting an output but it is not correct. I was finally able to attach a sample text file to try the code on. The hyphen and apostrophe value are correct, but not the semi colon and comma. I'm assuming I'll have to deal with these two separately? Because the same rule does not apply for these it does for apostrophe and hyphen.

Comment: What do you mean the same rule does not apply? The code makes it look like you want the same rule. Are you meaning semi-colon and comma do not need characters on both sides, but just a character before it? If so, yes you will need to check for those separately than apostrophe and hyphen. Or you can update the `if` statement I mention above to have a few `or` clauses in it, checking for only a character after the index if apostrophe or hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably keep it simpler than that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
sample = "I'd rather take a day off, it's hard work sitting down and writing a code. It's amazin' how some people find this so easy. Bunch of know-it-alls."

punc = "!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~" 
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

d = {}
for i, char in enumerate(sample):
    if i < 1:
        continue

    if i > len(sample) - 2:
        continue

    if char in punc:
        if char not in d:
            d[char] = 0

        if sample[i - 1] in letters and sample[i + 1] in letters:
            d[char] += 1

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{"'": 3, ',': 0, '.': 0, '-': 2}
```

Dunno where you're getting the ";" from. Also your comma has a space next to it.. so it doesn't count here.. if that does count add a space to the letters variable.

Explanation of what's happening:

We initiate a dict and read in sample text as `sample` and iterate it character by character, using `enumerate` to play with the indexes. If it is too close to the end or start to qualify, we skip it.

I check the character before and after the one we're at using the `i` variable from enumerate. and add to it's count if it qualifies.

NOTE: despite the shebang, this code works in python2

Comment: This does not meet the criteria of only counting the punctuation between two letters.

Comment: Nice, looks a lot like my answer now :). Removing down vote.

Comment: Cheers for that :)

Comment: I can limit the punctuations to just punc = ",;,'" right?

Comment: you can make punc or letters whatever you like yep.. I just got mine from the `string` module.

Comment: ok so I edited the post (I know I know, I should have added it on as an update instead of changing my post, but I'm an idiot so I didn't) and now I get: KeyEror: 0. Anything that I'm doing wrong?